# Render Object from State in React(MovieDb Practice)

Tags: reactjs, api, themoviedb-api

(MovieDb practice)
Hi guys im trying to render the object stored in my state to the dom..when i console log it, i get all the results in the console but when i try to render it i just get one result displayed

So my question is how can i get all the names i get in console to render and access other properties from the object

here is my code for app.js

---

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import logo from './logo.svg';

import './App.css';

import Movie from './components/Movie';


class App extends Component {

state={
  movieTitle: undefined,

  movieOverview: undefined
}

  getMovie = async(e) =>{

    e.preventDefault();
  const api_call = await fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=spider&api_key=${api_key}`);

  const data= await api_call.json();

  const results=data.results;

  console.log(results);

  results.forEach((movie) => {
    console.log(movie.title);

    this.setState({
      moviesTitle:movie.title

    })
  })
}
render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">

      <button onClick={this.getMovie}>Get Movie</button>

    <Movie
      movieName={this.state.moviesTitle}
      movieInfo={this.state.movieOverview}
      />

    </div>
  );
}
}

export default App;
```

In my Movies Component i am just rendering out the name via props and i am only getting the first name

any help with refactoring/diff methods for looping over to get the results will also be appreciated
thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issue

When you set state using results.forEach, you are looping through the result and updating the state with one value from the result. So naturally the last value looped is getting updated. Instead you should put the whole result into the state.

Loop the state when rendering.

### Changes made:

1. Created a property with array value in state.
2. store all the results into state
3. map over the values in state to render

### Updated code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import logo from './logo.svg';

import './App.css';

import Movie from './components/Movie';


class App extends Component {

state={

  movies : []

}

  getMovie = async(e) =>{

  e.preventDefault();
  const api_call = await fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=spider&api_key=${api_key}`);

  const data= await api_call.json();

  const results=data.results;


  this.setState(() => ({
    movies: results
  }))

}
render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">

      <button onClick={this.getMovie}>Get Movie</button>

      {this.state.movies.map( ({title,overview}) => {
        return(
          <Movie 
            movieTitle={title}
            movieOverview={overview}
           />

        )

      })}

    </div>
  );
}
}

export default App;
```

Comment: thanx a lot! do you have any suggestions for limiting the number of the movies i fetch like limiting the movies to say 10 and creating a button for loading the next 10..?